# JPA repository with modified query. How to test it?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have no experience. I started to study testing. Is this repository correct? How to test it?

```
public class Person extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Tsid
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    private String patronymic;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate issue;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate expiry;
    private String authority;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private LocalDate birthDay;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Anamnesis> anamnesis=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query(value =
            """
                    SELECT person.* FROM person
                    INNER JOIN anamnesis ON person.id = anamnesis.person_id
                    INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = anamnesis.employee_id
                    INNER JOIN department ON employee.department_id = department.id
                    WHERE department.clinic_id = :id
                    ORDER BY person.firstname ASC 
                    LIMIT :size OFFSET (:page * :size);
                    """,
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Person> findAll(Long id, Integer page, Integer size);
}
```

I think it is unwise JUnit testing. How to test in my case?

Comment: That's done with in-memory databases (h2 in case of sql). Check [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database).

Comment: Don't use in memory databases for testing if you don't use them in production. Use TestContainers instead.

Especially with SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have many questions packed into this one post.

**Is this repository correct?**

How should we be able to tell? We do not know the requirements that you tried to model.

**How to test it?**

Some automatic testing would definitely be good. So have a repository with defined set of data. Run a query. Since you know the data in the repository you also know what response is to be expected. Run enough of queries on enough of data so you feel safe to say whether the repository works to expectations.

**I think it is unwise JUnit testing. How to test in my case?**

JUnit-testing is not unwise per se. In-Memory database is not necessarily the only way to go. What you need to ensure is that the above mechanism can work:

Define the database content, run the test, compare the result to the expectation.

If you want your tests to execute in parallel, you may need many databases in parallel. If they execute sequentially, you may end up having only one database.

Maybe it is not the fastest, but I run my tests sequentially (I think JUnit does that per default anyway) on MariaDB. Then I added a clean script (drop all tables) and a create/populate script into the test setup method.

That means for every test the database is cleaned and created from scratch before some queries would be fired. It allows me to predict the exptected results.
It also means my CI/CD pipeline needs to have a MariaDB in the background, and the tests take some time to execute.

But in the end I can be sure the database and the application work together as intended - otherwise the tests would have failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if it is a good approach for such case to use repository with a very custom query, then yes it would still be a good approach to use JPA. If you want to know about the design of your db, we will need more info and probably a different thread

Regarding **unit testing repositories** in general, you are right it is not wise. It makes some sense in your case, since you re using a custom query. But this is not really code you re testing, so in general you should be testing on the correct level, which would be functional-tests or manual testing, depending on your strategy.

Finally, if you still want to have some tests in unit-tests level, there are many ways. You can use *in-memory databases*, *DataJpaTest*, *TestContainers* and maybe more. See what suits you better